# Sum column values based on date in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *, sum(s.main_product_order) 
  FROM (SELECT od.id_order_detail,
               od.id_order,
               count(od.id_order) AS main_product_order,
               od.order_date,
               od.id_customer
          FROM ps_order_detail_with_lens_attribute od
         WHERE od.linkedto = 0
           AND od.id_customer = '52165'
         GROUP BY od.id_order) s
```

Sample data:

| id_order_deatil | id_order | main_product_order | order_date | id_customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 178708 | 60225 | 2 | 2017-01-28 | 52165 |
| 192102 | 64608 | 1 | 2017-02-24 | 52165 |
| 479845 | 154100 | 1 | 2018-07-04 | 52165 |
| 809013 | 253424 | 1 | 2017-09-18 | 52165 |

I would like to sum the column main_product_order by date. I would like to calculate the sum of main_product_order a customer has at that point in time.

Expected result:[image]

Comment: Provide sample data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) which must produce shown desired output.

Comment: the first image shows the sample data of the table and second is the expected result

Comment: Do you want us to retype your structure and source data using the screenshot? really?

Comment: I have edited the question and no I don't expect to type the structure.

Comment: Shown desired output cannot be obtained from shown sample data. Yes, there is no problem to concatenate `'ch'` to numetic value. But where the timepart for `order_date` value must be taken from?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need in

```sql
SELECT *,
       SUM(main_product_order) OVER (ORDER BY order_date) - main_product_order
FROM source_table;
```

?

`source table` in this case should be the subquery from your query aliased as `s`.